# Function inside function vs function returns function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, return

I am studying JavaScript and I can't understand this.

```
function Out1()
{
    function In1()
        {
            console.log("text inside function In1");
        }
    return In1();
}


function Out2()
{
    return function In2()
        {
            console.log("text inside function In2");
        };
}

Out1();    // text inside function In1
Out2();    //
```

Out2(); outputs nothing in console. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `Out2` returns an anonymous function which needs execution to produce your expected output. `Out2()()` would do that.

Comment: @LinusKleen: It's not anonymous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Out2(); outputs nothing in console. What I am doing wrong?

`Out2` returns a reference to the function it created. It doesn't *call* that function. You could call it by using `()` on the returned reference:

```
//  vv-------- These call `Out2`   
Out2()();
//    ^^------ These call the function referenced returned by `Out2`
```

E.g.:

```
var f = Out2(); // `f` is now a reference to the `In2` function
f();            // This calls `In2`
```

Comment: Thanks T.J Crowder. In fact, you answered 2 questions at once. First one was the title one, and the second one (I hope I am not wrong) the need of the () after the variable that makes a closure to obtain the return.